# Ubuntu 20.04 running extremely slow

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, gpu

Recently, my computer has been running extremely slow (sometimes, it takes more than a second for a letter to appear after pressing the keyboard; it seems like the running speed periodically slows down then it starts running normally and then it slows down again).

I guess, some of the updates or kernel have caused the computer to slow down; in the past, I had similar problems due to the graphic card driver. Therefore, I reinstalled the graphic card drivers but the running speed has not been restored to normal.

The drivers have been reinstalled by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Below is the screenshot of the graphic card driver and CUDA:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.48.07    Driver Version: 515.48.07    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 28%   50C    P8    16W / 260W |    336MiB / 11264MiB |      6%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2151      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                213MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3995      G   ...mviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer        2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4226      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              118MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The kernel version is 5.4.0-80-generic

Some of the newest kernel versions caused the network card driver not to work and the GPU didn't work either.

Does anyone know what could cause such a slowdown and what might fix the issue?

Comment: Check ```top``` to figure out if there's some process that's taking up a lot of the work. I also noticed you have teamviewer running. Are you using the device through teamviewer? If yes, network lag is the explanation.